# How to change font to Marathi

Tags: c#, .net

I need to change my all lable language to marathi if i am selecting the value from combobox marathi. For that i am using Bharat01 font. but it gives error.
Other languages worked properly.if i am selecting spanish it convert hello into spanish also french it converts.but in marathi it gives error
here is my code..

```
 public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {

            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void label1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            comboBox1.Items.Add("English");
            comboBox1.Items.Add("Spanish");
            comboBox1.Items.Add("French");
            comboBox1.Items.Add("Bharat01");
            comboBox1.SelectedIndex = 0;
        }

        private void comboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            if (comboBox1.SelectedItem.ToString() == "English")
            {
                ChangeLanguage("en");
            }
            else if (comboBox1.SelectedItem.ToString() == "Spanish")
            {
                ChangeLanguage("es-ES");
            }
            else if (comboBox1.SelectedItem.ToString() == "Bharat01")
            {

                ChangeLanguage("bh-BH");

            }
            else
            {
                ChangeLanguage("fr-FR");
            }
        }
        private void ChangeLanguage(string lang)
        {
            foreach (Control c in this.Controls)
            {
                ComponentResourceManager resources = new ComponentResourceManager(typeof(Form1));
                resources.ApplyResources(c, c.Name, new CultureInfo(lang));
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Wouldn't it be a **LOT** easier if you added the culture string as the combo item's *value*?

Comment: Also be careful with fonts for 8bit Indian Encondings - they map ASCII code points to characters of Indian alphabets, but are not useful with Unicode.

Answer (score 1):

You are confusing Culture and UiCulture with Font.

For content to be in Marathi language, the culture should be set to "mr-IN".

Try calling `ChangeLanguage("mr-IN")` to change the language culture to Marathi. Once you get that working, then change font.

Answer (score 0):

For marathi try `ChangeLanguage("mr-IN")`.
Ref: [Reference Doc](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee825488(v=cs.20).aspx)